# What do gold medals on games in the plaza mean?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza

The most recent update (April 16th, 2015) to Streetpass added two new games, the Game Vault, and other upgrades. However, I don't recall anything in the Nintendo Direct video nor in any articles about the gold stars I now see on some of my games. In the picture, you can see that Find Mii I & II, Mii Force, and Flower Town all have gold stars next to them.

I so far haven't been able to find anything online about them. At first I thought it might be for finishing a game but I haven't finished Flower Town by far. I *have* finished the main campaigns of the other two games, but Mii Force isn't perfected.

What do the the gold medals on these games mean?

[image: Streetpass screenshot of Flower Town with a gold star]

Comment: Do you have all of the hats from the 3 games that have 3 stars?

Comment: @AndrewB I didn't consider that. I went and checked a list, as I thought it might be plausible, but I'm still missing most of the Find Mii II Secret Quest hats. Unless the Secret Quest hats don't count, then that's not it either. :(

Comment: When you say you've not finished the flower game, how many species do you have? Perhaps it doesn't require all 80 to consider the main quest finished.

Answer (score 3):

This community wiki answer will try to list circumstances in which people have or have not earned medals in an attempt to codify what's necessary for them.

For most of the sub-games, it is known that collecting all the related achivements is not necessary.

- Find Mii 1/2's medal seems to disappear if the player restarts a quest in order to collect hats. Therefore, it is not based on "have all hats". Odds are it means "has completed the (current) quest".
- Mii Force's medal does not require the player to have collected all gems or all titles, so it might mean "beat the game once".
- Flower Town's medal does not require the player to have completed all jobs. Likely to be based solely on earning the Master Gardener's Crown.
- Warrior's Way's medal remains even if the player starts a second quest. Therefore, it probably means "beat the game once".
- Monster Manor's medal remains even if the player starts a second quest. Therefore, it probably means "beat the game once".

Puzzle Swap is simple: If you have all the panels completed, you get the medal.

Comment: There are two more games: Ultimate Angler (fishing) and Battleground Z (zombie). For the zombie game you probably obtain the medal after beating the game once. For the fishing game you probably need to complete each island to get the medal.

Answer (score 1):

According to [GameFAQs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/625899-streetpass-mii-plaza/71641659):

> The medals are only to show you beat the main portion of that game.

Comment: This can't be true, I've completed Find Mii and Find Mii II and I don't have the medal on display for that game.

Comment: @AndrewB Have you completed both normal and secred quest of Find Mii 2?

Comment: Yes I have, completed them quite some time ago

Comment: @AndrewB How many times? Have you missed any room?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, no. I'm not 100% certain how many times but at least 10, I've gone to quite a few airports with that sucker.

Comment: @AndrewB IIRC I've obtained that medal only after my last completition of Find Mii, not after the update, maybe you have to end it again to trigger the medal.

Comment: @AndrewB Quoting the thread I've linked: "I finished Find Mii 2 (after finishing Find Mii) and did finally receive the medal. Though after the update Find Mii and Find Mii 2 were both on the finished screen so not sure why I had to play through them again to get the medal."

Comment: You definitely have to complete the games again after the update for them to register as completed.

Comment: @Whelt: Not true for me; I got the Find Mii 1/2 medal without entering it. I think I'll start a community wiki answer.

Comment: @Toomai I've got the Find Mii medal without entering it too after the update, but now it's disappeared, probably because I've restarted the misson to get the missing hats.